# Proof of the Frobenius Norm is the trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, machine-learning, principal-component-analysis

My professor presented the following in class and I have not been able to construct the proof and wondered if someone could explain this please? This is looking at the reconstruction error for PCA.
$W$ is $Fxd$ dimensional meaning that the number of features > number of samples.

Subject to the constraints that $W^TW = I$ so that we cannot arbitrarily minimise the Frobenius norm by altering $W$.

The relationship he asserts is the following:
$||X-WW^TX||_F = Tr[(X-WW^TX)^T(X - WW^TX)]$

When I consider the matrix $WW^T$ as $F×F$ dimensional, does this matrix have a $d×d$ submatrix that is the identity where there is padding of zeros in the remaining columns/rows? Does this impact the proof in any way?

Comment: The relationship your professor asserts is a general property of the Frobenius norm, though you are missing a square root on the trace operator. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm

Comment: I have looked at the wikipedia article but it was not immediately apparent as to why it is the sum of the diagonal elements and hence the trace. Could you maybe explain why this is the case please @AndrewShedlock

Comment: @InvestingScientist Note that the Frobenius norm is the *square root* of this trace

Comment: @InvestingScientist Note that for any matrix $M$, the diagonal entries of $M^TM$ is the sum of the squares of the corresponding column

Comment: @BenGrossmann that makes sense. A lot of sense actually - I can see this now. Thank you